# Script Automation using Microsoft Sharepoint forms

Tags: sharepoint, virtualization, vmware, virtual-machine

I am currently creating a prototype on how we can use microsoft sharepoint using forms(labels) to input certain fields(e.g. VM name, VM Operating System) and it will automatically generate the .vmx file with the details that is stated in the fields. After the .vmx file is created, using a Virtual Machine player, the .vmx file can be executed and the virtual operating system will load. Currently, I am reading up on the variables in the .vmx file. And which variables are important so we can automate this process, rather than create the .vmx file manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

kindly go through the blog link provided below that should be a help for you

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sergeim/archive/2008/06/03/create-vm-hyper-v-via-code-net-version-create-vm-programmatically.aspx

Comment: But I am still unsure how to use the codes to create in sharepoint. Any step by step guide in creating the form in sharepoint and with a click of a button, VMX file is created along with VMDK file with the relavant variables inputted in the form.

Comment: in SharePoint you would have to create a custom webpart in which you have to add the text boxes to get the inputs required for VM list can be obtained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136944(VS.85).aspx then on button click write the code provided in above link